# Where are libc++ headers located on Mac OS X Mavericks?

Tags: c++, clang, osx-mavericks, libc++

I'd like to take a look at the headers and want to know where they are.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

After you install Xcode it's located here:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/c++/v1
```

Mac OS X 10.9+ no longer uses GCC/libstdc++ but uses libc++ and Clang.

**Update**: After the XCode 6.0.1 update the headers are now located here:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1
```

Comment: Thanks to Jeffrey Thomas's answer below, I found that if xcode is not installed (only commandline tools), they can be found in `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1` (at least in Yosemite, will update answer if different in Mavericks)

Comment: So in Mavericks it's `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/c++/v1`

Answer (score 4):

`/usr/lib/libc++.dylib` it's a softlink.

```
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel       14 Oct 24 19:27 libc++.dylib -> libc++.1.dylib
```

`/usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib` is the current version.

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  1405296 Oct 24 19:26 libc++.1.dylib
```

---

`clang -print-search-dirs` shows you where it builds code from

```
programs: =/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
libraries: =/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/5.0
```